# Работа с Excel (управление активами). Ведение портфеля

Tags: excel

Есть необходимость в процессоре данных, с помощью которого можно вести портфель активов (акции/валюта/монеты)
Основные данные ввода - когда купил/продал, сколько и по какой цене.

Есть уже рабочий вариант, но он довольно громоздкий и неудобный (для каждого актива должна быть отдельная таблица/вкладка). Это очень сильно усложняет процесс ввода данных и сбора информации.

Хочу поместить все операции покупки/продажи в одной таблице - ок, готово. НО!

Когда, скажем, есть 10 разных акций, по 10 разных покупок (цены и кол-ва) - посчитать усреднённую цену любой из них становится нереальным (по крайней мере я не нашёл решение).

Для отображения усреднённой цены в старой версии таблицы использовал обычную ссылку на ячейку (ряд выше), где записаны все данные о предыдущей покупке/продаже и, тем самым "ступень за ступенью" excel считает правильную цену и количество.

Когда же все купить/продать акций/монет скопом - ссылка на предыдущую ячейку не имеет смысла (так как в ней может быть другая акция/монета).
Просто суммировать с формулой если не работает = сумма купленных монет (именно сумма в эквиваленте потраченных денег) / на сумму количество купленных монет {конечно, отнять сумму и кол-во проданных} выдаёт ошибочные данные (из-за разных сумм и количеств покупок).

Мне может помочь формула, которая даст возможность поделить/умножить/отнять и тд значение ячейки, которая находится в одном ряде с ячейкой названия актива. Но всё никак не могу её найти.

Следовательно вопрос:

Есть ли готовые решения по ведению своего портфеля в excel? Да, есть более удобные приложения и тд, но я бы хотел завязать всё именно в excel.

Какие формулы можно использовать для решения этой проблемы?
Что я упустил?
Можно ли не увеличивать количество таблиц, внося данные об операциях в одну, которая высчитает: сумму инвестиций, количество купленных монет, прибыль от продажи и, самое главное, усреднённую цену актива?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: усредненная цена считается очень просто - общая стоимость поделить на общее количество акций. Предыдущие ячейки для этого расчета не нужны. Продолжайте держать одну фирму на одном листе и просто сделайте одну сводную, куда переносите нужные данные. А так из этого описания сложно понять, что на самом деле вам требуется.

Comment: Я понимаю, но это не работает в случае, если одну и ту же акцию покупаю разными количествами и ценами

Comment: Может есть другие решения для ведения активов? Планирую заняться созданием crm для этого. Но для начала стоило бы разобраться с excel

Comment: Если в Excel - осваивайте VBA (макросы). Будет намного гибче, чем работа с формулами.